# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I've met a problem which I can't solve. The all problem is after user is logged in. I have using `useEffect()` to get user by using secret token from `localstorage`. Of course the data looks fine, secret is fine, get request is fine too, but.. I'm using `useContext` with `setUser` and `user`. So when I get a data I'm setting it to `setUser(res.data)` like this. Than in `<img src='${user.image[1]}' alt=''/>` I'm getting an error like this:

[image: 1]

The data I've got is fine as I said, but front can't reach it for somehow reasons. Is that problem reason cause `useEffect()` loads too late, cause front was already loaded?

I was used console to check what I've got from `user`, so result was fine, I'm getting full user with username, image(array), secret and more. But if I change from `<img src='${user.image[1]}' alt=''` to `<img src='${user.image}' alt=''` the page with username on top is loaded but getting error saying that got array. But page looks fine, just there is no image in it. And than if I change back to `user.image[1]` while user is logged in, the image will appear! But if user logout and login back then get the same error as it was in the beggining.

More about code: The component where I'm using `useEffect()` is `UserTrigger`. Then I'm importing it to component `Toolbar` with syntax `{isLoggedIn && <UserTrigger/>}`. `isLoggedIn` is boolean in localstorage which is setted when user login.

There's my code:

UserTrigger:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainContext from '../context/MainContext';
import { get } from '../helper/helper'

export default function UserTrigger() {
    const { user, setMessage, setUser, isLoggedIn } = useContext(MainContext);

    const nav = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUser() {
            const secret = window.localStorage.getItem('secret')
            console.log('secret', secret)
            const res = await get(`user/${secret}`)
            console.log(res.data.image[0])
            setUser(res.data)
        }
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            fetchUser()
        } else {
            nav('/login')
        }
    }, [])
    console.log(user)
    return (

        <div className='toolbar__user'>
            <img src={user.image[1]} alt="" />
            <h2>{user.username}</h2>

            <button onClick={() => { setMessage(''); setUser(null); nav('/'); window.localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn'); window.localStorage.removeItem('secret') }}>
                Logout
            </button>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Toolbar:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainContext from '../context/MainContext';
import UserTrigger from './UserTrigger';

export default function Toolbar() {

    const { setMessage, isLoggedIn } = useContext(MainContext);
    const nav = useNavigate()

    return (
        <header className='toolbar'>
            {/* Logo */}
            <div className='toolbar__logo'>
                <img src={require('../images/CartoonMatch.png')} alt='logo' />
            </div>

            {/* Links */}
            <div className='toolbar__links'>

                <div className="toolbar__drop">
                    <button className="dropbtn">Products</button>
                    <div className="dropdown-content">
                        <Link to="/feature/premium">Premium Features</Link>
                        <Link to="/feature/subscription">Subscription Tiers</Link>
                        <Link to="/feature/plus">Cartoon Plus</Link>
                        <Link to="/feature/gold">Cartoon Gold</Link>
                        <Link to="/feature/platinum">Cartoon Platinum</Link>
                        <Link to="/feature/night">Swipe Night</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Link onClick={() => { setMessage(''); }} to='/learn'>Learn</Link>
                <div className="toolbar__drop">
                    <button className="dropbtn">Safety</button>
                    <div className="dropdown-content">
                        <Link to="/safety/guide">Community Guidelines</Link>
                        <Link to="/safety/tips">Safety Tips</Link>
                        <Link to="/safety/policy">Safety & Policy</Link>
                        <Link to="/safety/report">Safety & Reporting</Link>
                        <Link to="/safety/security">Security</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Link onClick={() => { setMessage(''); }} to='/support'> Support </Link>
                <Link onClick={() => { setMessage(''); }} to='/download'> Download </Link>
            </div>

            {isLoggedIn && <UserTrigger />}
            {!isLoggedIn && <button className='toolbar__signin' onClick={() => { nav('/login') }}>Sign In</button>}
        </header>
    );
}
```

Sorry for bad English, but I hope you understand me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you that this is failing:

```
user.image[1]
```

Because the `image` property on `user` is `undefined`.  This is taking place in an asynchronous operation:

```
setUser(res.data)
```

So a couple of things are true at the moment:

1. We don't know what default `user` has before that `setUser` operation takes place.
2. We don't know what value `user.image` has *before* or *after* that `setUser` operation takes place.

But in any event, at the time you try to read `user.image[1]`, clearly `user` *is* defined but `user.image` *is not*.  You can use optional chaining to only use the value when it's present, for example:

```
user.image?.[0]
```

Basically any object or property which *could* be `null` or `undefined` could be optionally chained.  So if it were also possible for `user` to be `undefined` then you'd extend the optional chaining to this:

```
user?.image?.[0]
```

And so on.  Alternatively, you could conditionally not show the element(s) at all if there's no value to display, for example:

```
{
  user && user.image ?
    <img src={user.image[1]} alt="" /> :
    null
}
```

Here we check if both `user` and `user.image` exist and have "truthy" values before trying to use them.  Otherwise no output is displayed for that particular part of the UI.

There are a variety of ways you can structure your markup around conditionally checking for values.  But any way you look at it, the overall point is that if your data structures and logic allow for certain values to not exist sometimes then you need to check for that before using those values.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you response. Sorry for giving too less information, I'm still studying so don't know much how to ask a question properly and make easily to understood my code. I will try you suggestion now and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: First when I tried with `image` it gives me `null`. And got next same error with `username`. So I've tried to do same thing and it works! Thank you so much!